# Do script tags with type "text/html" get executed in any browser?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, cross-browser

I'm setting up a web application which allows some users to create plugins. These plugins may contain client-side templates which are rendered by JavaScript. The template code is placed in a `script` tag with `type="text/html"`, as done with [iCanHaz.js](http://icanhazjs.com/) templates.

My worry is that someone will try to write a plugin which contains an XSS attack by including actual JavaScript code rather than just template code. I know that on current browsers, `script` tags with `type="text/html"` do not get executed as JavaScript, so it should be safe. Is this the case on all browsers? My worry is that there are browsers out there that blindly execute the code as JavaScript whenever they see a `script` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the documentation and that's how it's supposed to work. The best way to find out for sure is test it but all the major browsers behave correctly.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a link to the documentation you're referring to?

Comment: @alexsanford1 - http://developers.whatwg.org/scripting-1.html#attr-script-type and http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT